# Open filedialog when pluggin in pi pico

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I want to execute my script in a specific folder of my pc, there is something in micropython that can open filedialog to choose that when the script start?

Comment: Please give more detail on what you're trying to do. Do you want something to happen automatically *on your PC* when you connect the Pico to the PC with a USB cable? The Pico can't do that by itself, you'll need to configure something on the PC side. What language is your script written in?

Comment: I want to open a filedialog like the tkinter filedialog but in micropython when the script start and store the path of the folder

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. Where do you want the file dialog to appear - on your PC? Then you need to write or configure something on the PC, not on the Pico. MicroPython running on the Pico cannot make something happen on your PC by itself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.